# Trying to allow user to use either capital or lowercase letters in Hangman code

Tags: python

I'm writing a hangman game in python for class. The user is told they have guessed incorrectly when they put a lower case when it is upper case and vice versa. Also when there is a space in the input it displays as an underscore (`_`) as well.

```
def gettingWord(theWord, lettersGuessed):
    count = 0
    blank = ['_ '] * len(theWord)

    for i, c in enumerate(theWord):
        if c in lettersGuessed:
            count = count + 1
            blank.insert(count-1,c)
            blank.pop(count)
            if count == len(theWord):
                return ''.join(str(e) for e in blank)
        else:
            count = count + 1
            blank.insert(count-1,'_')
            blank.pop(count)
            if count == len(theWord):
                return ''.join(str(e) for e in blank)
```

The code itself works I just want to know how I can fix this issue. Can anyone help?

Comment: There’s `lower()` method, I.e `if c.lower() in letterGuessed.lower()`

Comment: Thanks! Do you happen to know how to fix the empty spaces from becoming underscores as well?

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding correctly you want the user to be able to use uppercase and lowercase characters without affecting the result. If that's the case then you can use string's method lower() in order to turn each character the user guesses lowercase. In your function you could just add these two lines in the beginning:

```
theWord = theWord.lower()
lettersGuessed = [c.lower() for c in lettersGuessed]
```

First you turn the word to guess into lowercase, and then you turn each character in lettersGuessed lowercase (assuming `lettersGuessed` is a list of characters, if it's a string then you can just write `lettersGuessed = lettersGuessed.lower()`). This way all characters will be lowercase so the answer will depend on the character only and not on the casing.

Answer (score 0):

Convert both the character and the letters guessed to lowercase to ignore case.  If the character is whitespace, you also want to insert the character so you should add `or not c.strip()` to the if check to also insert the character if its whitespace.

Also, just to reduce code duplication, you should try and remove the duplicate code out of the if/else blocks, this will help with maintaining this or changing the logic in the future.

```
def gettingWord(theWord, lettersGuessed):
    count = 0
    blank = ['_ '] * len(theWord)

    for c in theWord:
        if c.lower() in lettersGuessed.lower() or not c.strip():
            blank.insert(count, c)
        else:
            blank.insert(count, '_')

        count = count + 1
        blank.pop(count)
        if count == len(theWord):
            return ''.join(str(e) for e in blank)
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert everything to lowercase, and strip spaces.

All the words in the word bank should be lowercase

When getting input:

```
letter = input('Enter a letter: ').lower().strip()
```

That should fix your problems with spaces and casing.